# Access to the C:\ and D:\ restricted for local admin

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy

One of our servers, TTSA, has no group policies applied to it when logging in as a local admin (other than the local policy), yet access to the C:\ and D:\ are still restricted.

I've checked the local policy, and sure enough there is no restriction on these drives set (Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows Explorer -> Hides these specified drives in My Computer / Prevent access to drives from My Computer).

Does anybody know what else could be restricting access to these drives for local admin, or if there is perhaps more settings in GP that could be causing this that I am unaware of? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried running RSOP? That should rule out Group Policy. Is it a terminal server by any chance? Also you say as **a** local admin - have you tried creating a brand new local admin account and seeing if that has the issue.

Comment: @Dan - It is indeed a terminal server. Just run RSoP (neet tool, much easier then scouring through the output from the cmd GPresult), and neither of the keys mentioned in my post are in there. Will try creating a new admin account now and see if that does the trick. Thanks.

Comment: I have hunch - I can't remember the reg path, but I suspect that the regkeys are in the Terminal Services installation folder thing (You know the whole "change user /install" thing). Let me Google!

Comment: Ha, created a new admin account (in the exact same groups as the built-in local admin), and it allowed me access. Just having a look at your answer now. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, if that worked then it's probably NOT the issue in my answer. You can either use regedit to edit the other users NTUSER.DAT file, or just delete the account and start again (Probably easier)

Comment: Agreed that it is easier, and I think I'll just probably do that and then rename the new one I set up. Just out of interest though, when logged in as the user that has the problem, do you know what key I am looking for to allow access? I assume it is not the one in your answer?

Comment: It'll be in users hive, under "Software\Policies". It *should* be safe to delete everything in there, but the usual warnings apply!

Comment: Found it - `HKEY_LOCAL_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`. I set the NoViewOnDrive key to '0', logged off and back on and it is sorted. Detailed description here - [link](http://www.pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/1157). Thanks for you help with this.

Comment: You should post what you've done and accept it as the answer. This is encouraged on SF :)

Comment: Was already on it, although I'm not allowed to accept it for 2 days!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the issue is because, once applied at any time through Group Policy, the 'Prevent access to drives from My Computer' policy setting is not reset in registry when a policy that sets it is no longer called.

To fix, change the 'NoViewOnDrive' key in the location below to '0' (to allow access to all drives) -

`HKEY_LOCAL_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`

Here is a detailed description of the key, and how to restrict access to specified drives if required - http://www.pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/1157

Answer (score 2):

What I suspect has happened is that a user with GPO's applied has installed software by using the

```
change user /install
```

command. Browse to the following registry location

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Terminal Server\Install\
```

And see if you have a key anywhere under there called "Policies". (Possibly \Software\Policies) If so, then this key is probably being applied, at logon, to all users (Including administrators). I'm afraid this is off the top of my head and I don't have a Terminal Server to view right now, but hopefully this will point you the right way.

You'll need to delete it (Take a backup first!) in order to resolve this issue.

Comment: Did have a quick look, and as you suspected above, this was not the answer. Have sorted though, thanks for you help along the way.